# Eclipse / LibGDX can't load Tools extension -> Particle Effects

Tags: eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to add the LibGDX "Tools" extension to an existing project in order to use a particle emitter, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I initially built the particle emitter I'm trying to use in another workspace, but I've copied the particle emitter file into the assets folder of this current project and I've copied over the code that was working in the other project. When I run the other project it runs fine, but in this one I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: particle.png
```

As per the documentation, I've added the following line to the build.grade file in the root of my workspace:

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
```

The documentation says I then have to "refresh gradle dependencies" but there doesn't seem to be any option to do that in Eclipse (I'm using version 3.8.1 in case that helps).

So I suppose my main question is how do I refresh the gradle dependencies? I read one post somewhere that said you right-click on the project and choose "Refresh Dependencies" from the Gradle menu, but there is no Gradle menu in the right-click menu (or anywhere else, as far as I can tell)

Comment: That's exactly where it should be. Are you sure that you've installed the gradle plugin for eclipse? Also, did you import your projects as gradle projects?

Comment: I used gdx-setup.jar to create the project, and I imported the projects using General -> "Existing Projects into Workspace". Not sure if a gradle plugin gets installed automatically but if not then I didn't install any gradle plugin, however it's worth noting that I set up both projects the same way, except one with the "Tools" extension checked in gdx-setup and the other without. The one with "Tools" checked, everything works. The one without is the one I'm trying to get working.

Comment: Update: I just checked my Eclipse preferences and there's a heading for "Gradle" so I presume the Gradle plugin is indeed installed.

Comment: Please read the wiki about how to setup your libgdx projects and IDE. You were supposed to import them as gradle projects, not existing projects.

Comment: Hmm the tutorial I followed explicitly said to import them as existing projects (though that was a 3rd party tutorial, not the one on the wiki)

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon in saying that I got it working. It's now working fine when launched in Desktop mode but when launched in Android mode I get this error: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: particle.png

Answer (score 0):

When poking around the menus in Eclipse I found an option to "Convert to Gradle project". On a hunch based on what was said in noone's first comment I tried that. This gave me a "Gradle" menu in the right-click menu, so I chose "Refresh All" from the Gradle menu and now it works :)